# Loading xml file with pegination php jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have an xml file with over 1000 records and the xml stracture is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<deals>

<deal>
<deal_id>1</deal_id>
<deal_title> <![CDATA[THE TITLE]]> </deal_title>
<deal_description> <![CDATA[THE DESCRIPTION]]> </deal_description>
<deal_url> <![CDATA[http://www.thedomain.com]]> </deal_url>
<deal_price>12.00</deal_price>
<deal_previous_price>68.00</deal_previous_price>
<deal_discount>82</deal_discount>
<deal_image> <![CDATA[http://www.thedomain.com/images/image.jpg]]> </deal_image>
<deal_shop>DEAL SITE NAME</deal_shop>
</deal>

</deals>
```

now how is it possible to load the .xml file using limitation to display the 10 records?

I will use this tutorial http://www.9lessons.info/2009/12/twitter-style-load-more-results-with.html

do display more records when the user presses the "load more" Button

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

You might use **SimpleXML** class to achieve that.

You can load your xml code like this:

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($your_xml_code);
$single_deal = $data->deals[0]->deal[/*numeric index of your deal*/];
```

[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) is docs and examples.

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea too, you could use GET like ?deals=50&limit=10, then use for loop to get all the deals, then parse them back into XML with SimpleXMLElement::asXml();

Comment: Yap :) now, two of us will just wait for someone else who will integrate whole solution in usable piece of code ;) cheers

Comment: I will grab a beer and wait for your solution. Of course, you're not getting anywhere without upvote from me, if you are not as lazy as I'm to do that :)

Comment: Actually I am REALLY lazy, but also bored right now, so I might just do that.

Comment: @Maxorq is there any possibility to intergrate it?

Comment: I'm writing code for that right now, but turns out SimpleXML isn't the best at actually editing the XML, so I think I'm gonna try writing it with DOM.

Comment: Actually, I give up, maybe someone else could take it from here, I have no idea how DOM works... http://pastebin.com/pu4ZHArh

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need a little PHP script to cut the XML after x number of lines, just like there is ajax_more.php in the example you provided.
I don't really know too much about XML in PHP, I always just parse it into associative array; maybe that would be the way to go here too?
Parsing into array, cutting off not important lines, then encoding into XML again?